# Very basic OrientDB/TinkerPop property graph DB questions

Tags: java, sql, orientdb, tinkerpop, rexster

Thanks in advance for your patience with what may be an array of stupid questions.

I'm re-engineering a legacy enterprise application from the ground up and have down-selected to OrientDB for the underlying graph database.  After perusing the OrientDB Google group, the various Wikis, etc I am left more than a little confused about what best practices apply and where to get started.  More specifically:

1. Am I correct in my understanding that with 1.6.4 (or later) I will
   need to leverage TinkerPop Blueprints in order to build a graph
   database?
2. If so, am I obliged to use Gremlin or is the extended SQL
   provided by OrientDB still available to me?
3. Should I, ideally, be creating the initial (non-embedded) database programatically through
   the TinkerPop APIs or establishing the structure via OrientDB's native console?
4. Does a blueprints implementation preclude me from
   using clusters or classes (can I still use the inheritance structure
   built into OrientDB)?
5. Given that I won't be using an embedded
   database, is Rexster obligatory for a TinkerPop-based
   implementation?
6. Has anyone heard wind of a Rexster kibble to provide Cypher support? :D

The majority of my experience to date has been with MS SQL and Neo4J (as is likely implied by my questions).

Cheers,

Jon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've received a response to this question on the OrientDB Google group.  I'm going to call it answered, but would still welcome any input anyone may have.

Cheers,

Jon

Comment: This answer is not helpful at all. Assuming you still know where to find the original answer to your question on the OrientDB Google group, the rest of us can only guess.

Comment: That's fair.  Unfortunately, I no longer work with OrientDB and don't have the source link available.  In the future, I will be sure to include all of the details of the solution.